# useEffect and useState keep re-rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, use-effect

I have written some code. But when I run server and client. My client keep requesting API again and again.
I think issue is with useEffect and useState but I don't know how to fix. I have already tried different methods including async functions and by passing extra parameter.

For server I am using node.js, for client I am using React.js and MongoDB for database.

Here is my git repo.

https://github.com/ahmedmobin/pizza-master

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect is also triggered for every propChange as it does for componentDidUpdate.

To prevent this you need to provide a second argument as empty array for useEffect.

For Example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```